# log4j.properties File not found

Tags: java, web, log4j

I know this question was already asked but I can't find/understand my error message.
Here's the thing. 
I want to use log4j on an Apache Tomcat 8.5 with eclipse for a web application.
So log4j works and I created a log4j.properties file.
I placed it in my /src like it is recommended.
Now comes the confusing thing for me. I get an Error Message:

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (Das System kann die
>   angegebene Datei nicht finden)

After this error, I get the log I am expecting, so is there maybe a place the compiler searches the file before it searches in the src folder or do I have to add any other dependency.

In addition, I'm not using Maven.
THX

Comment: right click on the file and select Build Path/Add to Build Path

Comment: after doing this I get the following error:
"Description Resource Path Location Type
Archive for required library: 'src/log4j.properties' in project 'servletTest' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file"

Answer (score 0):

I would think you'd want to put this file in your src/main/resources so that it will be on your maven path automatically.